# Rails assets missing on production after precompile heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I had to set config.assets.compile = false in production.rb due to security vulnerability in heroku.

After that, I noticed a couple missing files in public/assets so I ran:

```
heroku rake assets:precompile
```

> I, [2018-06-27T00:04:19.538776 #4]  INFO -- : Writing
>   /app/public/assets/application-b8b220c46c76c987e22df9f17f8b738290e41c5113e680fccc1f1d61f708
>   7453.css I, [2018-06-27T00:04:19.539053 #4]  INFO -- : Writing /app/public/assets/application-b8b220c46c76c987e22df9f17f8b738290e41c5113e680fccc1f1d61f708
>   7453.css.gz

and then:

```
heroku restart
```

Log shows it created this css file, and I see it in the document head, however that document throws a 404 error. How did I screw this up?

Comment: you can compile in localhost as a production and then deploy also. `rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production`

Answer (score 0):

After you precompile assets you need to restart the heroku server with `heroku restart`.

Comment: forgot to mention, I did run heroku restart after the precompile.

Comment: Dang. Sorry, I got nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the 404 error after I noticed that my previous commit missed those css files. committed, pushed and the files were there. Still encountering other pipeline issues, but will post a new more specific question.

Comment: Yep, I tried and stackoverflow says I need to wait 2 days.

Comment: Argh! Sorry to be so fiesty.